# Why is it that W perp intersection with W is {0}?

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is:

If $$W^\perp$$ is a subspace of $$R^n$$

Then how is

$$W^\perp \cap W = [0] $$

Comment: Assume $v$ is in both $W$, $W^{\perp}$. Then $v$ is perpendicular to itself, and hence $\langle v , v \rangle = \|v\|^2 = 0$. Which vector(s) have length $0$? There's only one.

Comment: What is your definition of $W^\perp$? The answer ought to lie there.

Comment: You may be picturing something like a couple of planes and wondering how they could possibly intersect in just a single point. The simple explanation, in $\mathbb R^3$ anyway, is that if one is a plane then the other has to be a line (the normal to the plane through $0$). In higher dimensions, there are other directions, so your geometric intuition from $\mathbb R^3$ may fail.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $x\in W^\perp\cap W$. Then since $x$ is orthogonal to every vector in $W$, in particular, $x$ is orthogonal to itself i.e. $<x, x>=\lvert x\rvert^2=0$. So $x$ is  the zero vector.

Also note that the zero subspace is a valid subspace of all vector spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If you have a vector in both subspaces, call it $w$, then $w\cdot w=$ ...?

Answer (score 0):

Given an inner-product space $X$ and some $W\subset X$, then, by definition,

$$W^\perp:=\left\{x\in X:\langle x,y\rangle=0\text{ for every }y\in W\right\}.$$

Use this and Cameron Williams's post above to answer your question.